# Edge holes topology. How to make holes like this?

Tags: modeling

I do not understand how to properly make edge holes for a subsurf modifier.
What I want
[image: Pic]

[image: What I have]
What I have
(Some artifact on the corners)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extrude function to do this.

Lets say you have the following mesh:

[image: Example Mesh]

Now we need to add some extra edge loops to the area want want to extrude. This can be done by clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: Edgeloop 1]

Once for the top and repeat that for the bottom.

[image: Edgeloop 2]

Once for the side. **Do this also on the other side**

[image: Face Select]

Now we going to `Face Select` and select the part we want to extrude

[image: Face Select icon]

Now we can extrude the selected faces by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> and dragging it to the position you want.

You can add a few extra edges to it to control the subdivide but I find mostly that its not needed and just creates more vertex.

**Result**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this first: https://youtu.be/7k-FPC78FZ8 then add your subsurf afterwards. Let me know if that works for you - I tried it and it looked fine.

Try making your model first without subsurf then add the subsurf after you've created the 'hole'. I just went to face mode selected the faces that I wanted protruding inwards and clicked 'I' to extrude and scale inwards then click 'E' to extrude inwards. Then go to modifiers and add subsurf - it seems to be fine but needs a little defining on the end - so I added an edge loop (Control R) on each end to keep the shape.

Comment: Please help us make this a better site. Add more detail to your answers, not just links.